# Where do gravitational waves and general relativity coincide?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass, gravitational-waves

In the first ten seconds of this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iphcyNWFD10) the host says that gravitational waves were the result of two black holes merging. That would seem like there is then an origin for the force of gravity and what we experience on Earth is not an intrinsic property of mass.

Comment: Black holes have mass. That's why they create gravitational waves when they merge.  I don't see any contradiction between black holes creating gravitational waves when they merge and gravity being an intrinsic property of mass.

Answer (score 2):

A gravitational field like the gravitational field of the Earth is a static field, while a gravitational wave is an oscillating gravitational field. They are two different forms of the same thing.

As a comparison consider electromagnetic fields. A static charge produces a static electric field. However it is also possible to have oscillating electromagnetic fields like light and radio waves.

If a gravitational wave passes through a static gravitational field, e.g. when a gravitational wave passes through the Earth, the two gravitational fields simply add together. The end result is that the gravitational wave makes the gravitational field we feel on the Earth's surface oscillate. However gravitational waves are much, much weaker than static gravitational fields so the change in the Earth's gravity can only be measured using specialist equipment. In fact this change is exactly what the [LIGO experiment](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/) measures when it detects black hole mergers.

Comment: so how do these two types of fields interact with each other? The real problem I am having is understanding whether we are experiencing gravity due to the Earth's mass (space-time curvature) or due to waves coming from a source. How could it be both?

Comment: @SamBTz The two effects simply add. When no gravitational eaves are present we experience the static gravitational field of the Earth. When a gravitational wave passes through it makes the Earth's gravitational field oscillate around its static value. This oscilaltion is exactly what the LIGO experiment measured when it detected a black hole merger.

Comment: Are the gravitational waves coming from multiple directions, or just one? If it's just one, how is the whole sphere of Earth affected?

Comment: @SamBTz We do not "experience" gravitational waves, just the effects of spacetime curvature.

Comment: They only add in the weak-field limit (which is good enough for all practical purposes).